# android - Bug Status Bar and navigation Bar TRANSPARENT

Tags: android, statusbar, android-4.4-kitkat

I have a problem with the translucent statusbar only when opening of the app for the first time. Take a look at the screenshot:

http://i1335.photobucket.com/albums/w673/ductruongcntt/Screenshot_2014-06-26-14-17-26_zps1e9a56f4.png

Here is the XML of the Style I use which is including the translucent Status Bar:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.viewpagerindicator.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/indicatorTabHome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >
</com.viewpagerindicator.PagerSlidingTabStrip>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vpMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

and my theme:

```
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Thank you. I want my application transparent statusbar

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside your activity tag in the manifest. This'll ensure that the app opens full screen.

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```